# Call hitTest inside of touchesMoved

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an UIView which is on top of all other views and has overridden hitTest() method which always return itself:

```
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return self
    }
```

Then, when I make some operations using points from touchesBegan(), I need to pass hitTest() to the views below of the our UIView:

```
override public func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Do some operations
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // pass touch event handling to views below or change hitTest()
}
```

So basically, on the top UIView I'm overriding touchesBegan(), touchesMoved() and touchesEnded() methods. Then I need to handle touches, perform some operations and then, if needed, to pass to views below. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably simpler and better to solve your problem differently.

UIKit delivers a touch event by sending it to the window (the root of the view hierarchy) in a `sendEvent(_:)` message. The window's `sendEvent(_:)` method is responsible for finding the gesture recognizers interested in the touches, and sending the appropriate `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc. messages to the recognizers and/or the hit view.

This means that you can subclass `UIWindow` and override `sendEvent(_:)` to get a look at every touch event in the window, before the event reaches any gesture recognizers or views, without overriding any view's `hitTest(_:with:)` method. Then you pass the event along to `super.sendEvent(event)` for normal routing.

Example:

```
class MyWindow: UIWindow {

    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
        if event.type == .touches {
            if let count = event.allTouches?.filter({ $0.phase == .began }).count, count > 0 {
                print("window found \(count) touches began")
            }
            if let count = event.allTouches?.filter({ $0.phase == .moved }).count, count > 0 {
                print("window found \(count) touches moved")
            }
            if let count = event.allTouches?.filter({ $0.phase == .ended }).count, count > 0 {
                print("window found \(count) touches ended")
            }
            if let count = event.allTouches?.filter({ $0.phase == .cancelled }).count, count > 0 {
                print("window found \(count) touches cancelled")
            }
        }

        super.sendEvent(event)
    }

}
```

You can use this window subclass in your app by initializing your app delegate's `window` outlet to an instance of it, like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow? = MyWindow()

    // other app delegate members...

}
```

Note that UIKit uses `hitTest(_:with:)` to set the `view` property of a touch when the touch begins, **before** it delivers the touch-began event to the window. UIKit also sets each touch's `gestureRecognizers` property to the set of recognizers that might want the touch (recognizer state `.possible`) or are actively using the touch (states `began`, `changed`, `ended`, `cancelled`) before passing the event to the window's `sendEvent(_:)`. So your `sendEvent(_:)` override can look at each touch's `view` property if it needs to know where the touch is going.

Comment: Thanks! This approach seems very helpful for my task